# How to pass argument in Django Context Processor From Template

Tags: python, django

I want to pass an argument in context_processors.py from the template. if anybody knows please tell me.
this is my context_processors.py

```
def groupWiseCustomer(request,id):
    return {'groupWiseCustomer': CSSIList.objects.filter(CSSIGroup=id)}

{% for customer in groupWiseCustomer 1  %}
    <td>Hello World</td>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to pass a value from the template to this context processor.

Comment: The request is the only argument passed to the context processor. It is generally considered that the context processor can infer enough information from the request.

Comment: Wait do you want a context processor or a template filter / tag? Your example code in the template looks to be more a usecase for template filters / tags. Read the documentation on [How to create custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/)